# Processing Two Seperate JQuery Api Calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, geojson

I'm struggling to find a way to take the 'result' of two api calls and then process them together. In both calls I recieve JSON and then parse it in to a GeoJSON format. I then want to be able to put both of those geojson objects in to another function so assumedly they have to become 'global'?

I'm aware that I'm dealing with issues of asynchronicity here and the solution would probably to do both API calls in the same function? I can't quite work out how to do it.

PS There is a leaflet map created earlier on in the page, hence the map references.

```
###First API Call
    $.ajax({
      url:"PORT API URL",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(port_response){
      port_callback(port_response)
    }})


    function port_callback(port_response) {
        var port_geojson = {
            type: "FeatureCollection",
            features: [],
        };
        for (var i in port_response.data) {
            port_geojson.features.push({
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [port_response.data[i].longitude, port_response.data[i].latitude]
            },
            "properties": {
            "stationName": port_response.data[i].port_name
            }})}
        L.geoJSON(port_geojson).addTo(map);
    };


###Second API Call
    $("#single-postcode").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $result = $("#single-postcode-result").slideUp(),
            postcode = $("#single-postcode-input").val();
    $.get(encodeURI("POSTCODE API URL" + postcode))
    .done(function (data) {
        displayJsonResult($result, data);
        callback1(data)
        callback2(data)
    })
    .fail(function (error) {
        displayJsonResult($result, error.responseJSON);
    });
    });

    var displayJsonResult = function ($context, data) {
        $context.html(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4)).slideDown();
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
    }



    function callback1(data) {
        var geojson = {
        type: "FeatureCollection",
        features: [],
        };
            for (var i in data.result) {
                geojson.features.push({
                "type": "Feature",
                "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [data.result.longitude, data.result.latitude]
                },
                "properties": {
                "postcode": data.result.postcode
                }
                })};
                L.geoJSON(geojson).addTo(map);
                map.setView([JSON.parse(data.result.latitude),JSON.parse(data.result.longitude)], 14);


        };
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use ES6 Promise method to achieve this, Here is a simple example to call two asynchronous functions and having return some string.

```js
function firstFunction(duration) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      //you can call your ajax call here and put your success response inside resolve callback
        setTimeout(resolve("FirstObject"), duration);
    });
}
function secondFunction(duration) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(resolve("secondObject"), duration);
    });
}

var promiseAll = firstFunction(5000).then(() => {
    //promise all the method to get all result of all async calls
    return Promise.all([firstFunction(100), secondFunction(200)]);
})

let result = document.getElementById("result");

promiseAll.then((val)=>{ result.InnerHtml = "First and second Fullfillment done.." + val;
console.log("First and second Fullfillment done.. "+val)},
  (err)=>{console.log("one/all rejected "+err)})
```

```html
<p>Once you run the function you can see the return values from each function call</p>
<div id="result">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! My second API call is currently run after a button click event. Do you know how I would account for that? The first API call can run straight away, then the second API call has to happen after the click event, then I need to have a third function that processes the results from both of the API calls.

Comment: @Jamie2483, In that case, you can use store the result in two different objects with a global scope and use Object.assign(obj1, obj2) to your Geojson object use that for the third function. is that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this. Calling both api together!! and it will execute when both api succeed

```
   $.when( $.ajax( "/page1.php" ), $.ajax( "/page2.php" ) )
   .then( myFunc, myFailure );
```